# Uncaught TypeError: Popper.createPopper is not a function

Tags: javascript, function

The error (Uncaught TypeError: Popper.createPopper is not a function) it's always showing on the console. I read the bootstrap guide but nothing. This it's the order of my scripts.

Please anyone can resolve this

`

```
<!--end::Vendors Javascript-->
<!--begin::Custom Javascript(used by this page)-->
<script src="~/V3/assets/js/widgets.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="~/Chat/MainChat.js"></script>
<script src="~/V3/assets/js/custom/widgets.js"></script>
<script src="~/V3/assets/js/custom/apps/chat/chat.js"></script>
<script src="~/V3/assets/js/custom/utilities/modals/upgrade-plan.js"></script>
<script src="~/V3/assets/js/custom/utilities/modals/create-project/type.js"></script>
<script src="~/V3/assets/js/custom/utilities/modals/create-project/budget.js"></script>
<script src="~/V3/assets/js/custom/utilities/modals/create-project/settings.js"></script>
<script src="~/V3/assets/js/custom/utilities/modals/create-project/team.js"></script>
<script src="~/V3/assets/js/custom/utilities/modals/create-project/targets.js"></script>
<script src="~/V3/assets/js/custom/utilities/modals/create-project/files.js"></script>
<script src="~/V3/assets/js/custom/utilities/modals/create-project/complete.js"></script>
<script src="~/V3/assets/js/custom/utilities/modals/create-project/main.js"></script>
<script src="~/V3/assets/js/custom/utilities/modals/select-location.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="~/Builder/js/tether.min.js?v=2"></script>
//<script src="~/builder/js/bootstrap.min.js?v=2"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Builder/js/jquery.min.js?v=2"></script>
<script src="~/Builder/js/jquery-ui.min.js?v=2"></script>
 <script
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<script src="~/V3/assets/plugins/global/plugins.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Github buttons -->
<script async defer src="https://buttons.github.io/buttons.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/hierarchy-select.min.js?v=2"></script>
<script src="~/V3/assets/js/custom/utilities/modals/create-app.js"></script>
<script src="~/V3/assets/js/custom/utilities/modals/users-search.js"></script>

<script src="~/choose.js?v=9"></script>
<script src="~/chat/MainChat.js"></script>
<script src="~/Builder/js/form_builder.js?v=148"></script>
<script src="~/Xerox/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Xerox/main.js?v=4"></script>
<script src="~/Update/Update.js?v=5"></script>
<script src="~/waitjs/waitme.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/waitjs/waitme.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>   
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha256-CjSoeELFOcH0/uxWu6mC/Vlrc1AARqbm/jiiImDGV3s=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.13.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="~/V3/assets/js/scripts.bundle.js"></script>`
```

I read the bootstrap guide but nothing

Comment: ["_jQuery must come first, then Popper.js, and then our JavaScript plugins. ... src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js_"](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/).

Comment: could you please share the file, where you use `Popper.createPopper`? It has to be loaded after `popper.js` is loaded